# Jackson version with Maven in SpringBoot 2.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jackson, jackson-databind

When I update my project from SpringBoot 2.2.7 to 2.3.0, I encounter the following error when launching:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ToStringSerializerBase
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
```

I don't see any errors in Eclipse after the update.
I specify that I don't use Jackson directly in my pom.xml, but only external packages which use it (from mvnrepository.com).

So I think it was related to Jackson's upgrade from 2.10 to 2.11, and probably a Maven dependency from external package (jjwt-jackson use 2.9 for example).

In pom.xml, I see this:

Before (SpringBoot 2.9.7) :
[image]

After (SpringBoot 2.3.0) :
[image]

Can my explanation be correct ? And is there a solution with pom.xml (or anything else) to resolve this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are mixing up three different Jackson versions:

- 2.9 e.g. `jackson-databind-2.9.10.3`
- 2.10 e.g. `jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.10.1`
- 2.11 e.g. `jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.11.0`

This is not going to work, you must use the same Jackson version. Your particular problem with missing `ToStringSerializerBase` comes from using 2.9 with 2.10+.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! But this three different versions are used by 3 external opensource packages (SpringBoot (2.11), jjwt-jackson (2.9), and springdoc-openapi-ui (2.10), you can find them on mvnrepository ), and not for my project directly. So I can only hope that new versions will be released from this different project soon ?

Comment: You shouldn't mix libraries with different transitive dependencies. Just because they are published to maven central doesn't mean they will work **together**.

Answer (score 2):

Use [maven exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#dependency-exclusions) and exclude 2.9 & 2.10 versions from `jjwt-jackson` & `springdoc-openapi-ui` in your pom file.